# Error 500 some JS Files Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.3.1

My theme (Claue of MGS) has been working very good.
I updated my Magento version to 2.3.1, after that it started to generated some few errors that i've been solved.

Now i have this problem: My chrome console is generating some error 500 with some JS Files, the others are working good. In the console with those files say:

**jquery-storageapi.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

**lazyload.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

**ETC.. There are 14 different JS Files**

I've tried a lot of things (**deploy, permission, htaccess, etc**) but still can't solve  it.

Someone have any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried editing bootstrap.php to show errors to see what shows on screen when you try and load the above resources?

Comment: Did you find any solution of this till now.... please let me know..... i also facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in css/js path

run this query in mysql

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

after that clear the config cache

```
 bin/magento cache:clean config
```